# Хранить JSON-объект

Tags: jquery, json, javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли принятый JSON-объект хранить после его первой обработки обработчиком, чтобы при каком-то событии мне был доступен этот объект (как глобальный).
Может ли сделать объект видимым пока страница не перегружена?

Comment: я бы пересмотрел идею глобальности объекта, лучше сделать го видимым только для обработчика событий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data_storage;
...
function(data){
    var obj=JSON.parse(data);
    ... // вносятся изменения в obj
    data_storage=JSON.stringify(obj); 
}
...
var some_obj=JSON.parse(data_storage); // получение "копии" объекта
```

Comment: [не будет работать](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/gSHyf/)

Comment: Почему? Выведите в консоль JSON.parse(data_storage).c

Comment: хотя... "после его первой обработки"... ладно, тогда работает, просто идея странная.... чего бы просто объект не хранить

Comment: тут возникает сложный философский вопрос, в чем заключается первичная обработка, если `data[0]=function(){}` то клонировать через json не получится, может и вообще не получится, так как полное клонирование в json имеет некоторые трудности.

Comment: не стоит так глубоко копать, скорее всего речь идет об изменениях только тех свойств, которые поддерживаются в передаче через JSON

Answer (score 0):

надо клонировать объект, так как у нас заведомо enumerable, мы можем без всяких опасений использовать `JSON.*`:

```
$.get(url,function (data) {
    data[0]=""; //первое изменение data
    var stored = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); //клонируем
    data[1]=""; //другое изменяющие data
    console.log(data); // вывод измененной data
    $('#clickme').click(function () {
        console.log(stored); //вывод оригинальной data
    });
}, "json");
```

ну и как я говорил выше, лучше не делать глобальных объектов без сверхнеобходимости. 
так, же если вы встроите в процессе первичной обработки не enumerable свойства в объект, то клонировать такой объект честными методами не получится, примеры тому, function(), DOM объекты и прочее скажем

```
data[0]=function();
```

либо

```
data[0]=$('#mydiv'); data[1]=$('#mydiv').get(0);
```

[Демо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/PKpVC/)

как правильно заметил [[@Gedweb](/users/10995/gedweb)](/users/10995/gedweb) предполагается , что этот запрос будет выполнен один раз, в случае многократного запроса, нужно либо делать `.unbind()` либо, держать переменную в области видимости выше `$.get()`

Comment: при каждом вызове `$.get` на `#clickme` будет вешаться обработчик. Таким образом по клику на данный объект будет выполняться несколько итераций. Используйте `unbind`.

P.S. Как видите ваш код не идеален, я написал это что бы вы сдержали пыл в критике по отношению к другим.

Answer (score 0):

`handler.getJSON` - получаем и сохраняем в свойство объекта

`handler.data` - объект полученый из `JSON`

```
handler={
    data:null,
    getJSON:function(){
        // ... получаем и парсим JSON
        this.data=JSON.parse(string);
    }
}

console.log(handler.data)
```

Comment: и вы считаете что data= изменит handler.data ? вы глубоко заблуждаетесь. мало того, getJSON вообще не выполнится в такой конструкции, это просто объявление. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/HnkLH/ [и даже так](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/HnkLH/1/)

Comment: я не заблуждаюсь, я опечатался

Comment: да нет, заблуждаетесь, вызова getJSON не произойдет. кроме того, там ajax - асинхронный запрос по умолчанию, сразу после вызова (даже если сделать `handler.getJSON()` ) данные  нельзя использовать. именно поэтому я говорю о необходимости инициализации обработчика событий в callback  запроса.

Comment: @eicto, то что после вызова handler.getJSON() в handler.data будет находиться объект очевидно. А где вызывать метод и после брать свойство будет решать автор

Comment: @минусатор: откомментируйте

Answer (score 0):

```
// app namespace

var app = function() {

    var jsData;

    function get(){
        return jsData;
    }

    function set(data){
        jsData = data;
    }

    function printConsole(str)  {
        console.log(str +'>>> jsData = '+ JSON.stringify(jsData))
    }

    return {
        getData:get,
        setData:set,
        printData:printConsole
    }
}();

//...

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("hierarchy.php?id=2", showHierarchy); 
});

function showHierarchy(data) {

    app.printData(0); //undefined

    app.setData(data);
    app.printData(1); //object

    var jsData = app.getData(); //copy JSON-object to member-function and use it data
    console.log('Local data: '+ JSON.stringify(jsData));
}
```

Comment: Благодарю всех участников за консультации, идею создания глобального объекта уяснил. Выше моя конечная реализация этой идеи. Вопрос закрыт